# exporting data for analytics use in SaaS

Tags: export, analytics, amazon-redshift, business-intelligence, olap

We are a SaaS product and we would like to be able have per-user data exports that will be used with various analytical (BI) tools like Tableau or PowerBI. Instead of just managing all those exports manually, we thought of using some cloud database such as AWS Redshift (which will be part of our service). But then, it is not clear how is user will access those databases naturally, unless we do some kind of SSO integration with AWS.

So - what is the best practice for exporting data for analytics use in SaaS products?

Answer (score 1):

In this case you can build your security in to your backend API layer.

First you can set up processes to load your data to Redshift, then make sure that only your backend API server/cluster has access to redshift (e.g. through a vpc with no external ip access to redshift)

Now you have your data, you can validate your user as usual through your backend service, then when a user requests a download through the backend API, the backend can create a query to extract from redshift only the correct data based upon the users security role. In order to make this possible you may need to build some kind of security column into your redshift data model.

Comment: Thanks Jon, so the idea was to actually get rid of our own backend API layer, because in that case we will have to create connectors that use that backend API layer for each BI tool.. I was wondering if Redshift (or any other analytics-friendly cloud DB) has any kind of security model like that.

Comment: Most times people use the bi tool or application backend to implement the granular role based security, not the underlying DB. But  I'm sure it could be done with some kind of home grown synchronisation service.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming getting data to redshift is not a problem.

What you are looking for, if I understand correctly is a OEM solutions.
The problem is how does one mimic the security model you have in place for your SaaS offering.

That depends on how complex is your security model.
If it is as simple as just authenticate the user and he has access to all tenant data or the data can be easily filtered for user. Things are simple for you. Trusted authentication will allow you to authenticate that user and user filtering will allow you to show him all that he has access to.

But here is the kicker, if your security is really complex , then it can become really difficult to mimic it within these products.

Here for integrating tableau this link will help:- 
https://tableau.github.io/embedding-playbook/#

Power BI, this product am not a fan off. I tried to embed a view in one my applications and data refresh was a big issue.
Its almost like they want you to be a azure shop for real time reporting.( I like GCP more )
If you create the api's and populate datasets then they have crazy restrictions like 1MB/sec etc. 
On the other instances datasets can be refreshed only 8 times.

I gave up on them.

Very recently I got a call from Sisense and they seemed promising as well from a OEM perspective. You might was to try them.

Comment: thanks DSD, we are looking at OEMing too, but right now is more about how we export the data from our system in analytics-friendly way and do not reinvent the wheel. see answer to Jon's answer.